# Create custom cron in wordpress?

Tags: cron, wordpress, crontrigger

I have a wordpress page and i need to set this page in cron. How can i do it?
My wordpress page link is:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=popshop-import&category=32194&cate_id=1279
```

This page works fine when i run this url in browser. How can i set this to wordpress cron?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner can you guide me..

Comment: What do you want to do with this page?

Comment: @omer Farooq i want get the products from popshop api to woocommerce. so only i want this type

Comment: Well you can checkout my answer, it uses a very general view of using a simple rest api. You might have to make some minor changes to it. But at the end you should get all the data, once you have the data, you can then use any woocommerce import script to import the products to woocommerce.

Answer (score 1):

Well i dont have any experience with popshop api, but using the wordpress crons is pretty simple. You just have to create a function that does what ever you want, and then hook it into the wp_schedule_event function.

**Lets suppose POPSHOP API is a simple REST API. This is how you will make the cron job.**

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'popshop_api' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'popshop_api' );
}

add_action( 'popshop_api', 'running_popshop_api' );

function my_task_function() {
  $service_url = 'http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=popshop-import&category=32194&cate_id=1279';
  $curl = curl_init($service_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
  if ($curl_response === false) {
      $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' .   var_export($info));
  }
  curl_close($curl);
  $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
  if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
      die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
  }
  echo 'response ok!';
  var_export($decoded->response);

}
```

So the code uses curl to and looks for the response, if the response is not false it saves the data to the $curl_response variable, then you can var_dump/var_export it and do what ever you want with it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have one doubt my page in admin panel. so if i run this from cron means its ask login?

Comment: Well to be honest i dont have any experince with popshop api. This is just a demonstration for how a normal REST Api will work. In a real api there will be several paramters for authintication, like secret keys/api keys etc. I just did a quick search and looks like same is the case with your api, the keys are there to avoid users to login into the system maunally.
http://api.popshops.com/{API version}/{API key}/products.xml?catalog_key={Catalog key}